# Using Glob to set a filename into a variable?

Tags: php, glob

I am simply trying to set a variable to a filename, I know the start and end of the filename, but part of the filename is date stamped and is therefore variable.

However this simple test gives me an error

```
<?php 
$apps = (glob('/var/www/vhosts/smartphonesoft.com/httpdocs/fred/epf/file*.tbz');
echo $apps;
?>
```

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
>   unexpected ';' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/smartphonesoft.com/httpdocs/fred/showfile.php
>   on line 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an opening bracket that is not closed:

```
$apps = (glob('/var/www/vhosts/smartphonesoft.com/httpdocs/fred/epf/file*.tbz');
--------^
```

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by putting it into brackets or by echo'ing it. `glob` will always return an array of matching filenames. If no file is matched, the array will be empty. Try `print_r($apps)` to see what `glob` matched.

Comment: Thanks for the highlight that `glob` returns an array